# Errors using Node.js' import modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My issue is that after trying multiple methods for about a week and a half+, I still haven't been able to run node.js in the browser without running "node filename.js" in terminal. I've tried advice from a previous stackoverflow post, about 10-15 different different express/node we tutorials, help from a friend and different websites.
This is what I'm trying to run (my user routes from firebase). It works perfectly when I run it through terminal but otherwise, nothing works. Here's the snippet

```js
import Express from "express";
import path from "express";
const app = Express();
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.get('/user=:username', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/profile.html'));
});
```

When I run it in the browser (vsc live server) I get this error each time I try something. "Error resolving module specifier “express”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”."
I've also recently tried browserify but I kept getting errors saying some packages didn't download.

Comment: Why are you trying to run Node in the browser? Is this an attempet at SSR? You would not want to create an express server in the browser... I think you're missing some fundamentals here

Comment: The static file you trying to load are they React static file? Or?

Comment: @Dominik https://medium.com/@DanSiepen/top-15-sites-built-with-node-js-a6412638eb28, figured I could get something to work.

Comment: @Ntshembo Hlongwane, nope, mostly vanilla js

Comment: "Sites built with Node.js" means "Sites that run a Node.js backend," not "Sites that run Node.js in the browser." Dominik is right, you have a major misunderstanding what Node.js and Express are.

Comment: @GuyIncognito ok, i am not very familiar with this, that is why i am asking for help and trying to learn after putting a good effort to fix my problem before I asked for help.

Comment: @PaulAnthony I think it would be best for you to keep reading articles and learning. SO can't really help you here. Just know that node runs in the backend and you consume the APIs in the browser.

Comment: "It works perfectly when I run it through terminal" <-- then you don't have a problem, that's where it's supposed to run.

Comment: @GuyIncognito i will rephrase my question then, I am trying webpack now, if that does not work, what is your suggestion

Comment: Sorry, but sounds like you're still trying to go to a completely wrong direction. Your script is not meant to run on a browser and *it will never run on a browser* no matter what you try. Which is a good thing. It's a server script that's supposed to run in the terminal.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I get that, do you have any suggestions for running user routes in the browser?

Comment: No, doesn't seem like you get it. "Running user routes in the browser" is a nonsensical concept. Routes run in the server, not in the browser. If you want to access the routes from the browser you make an Ajax call.

Comment: thank you for finally answering my question